# How to ensure that object can be serialized to xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have this method to ensure that object can be serialized into binary file:

```
    public static bool IsSerializable<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return typeof (T).Attributes.HasFlag(TypeAttributes.Serializable) || obj is ISerializable;
    }
```

but i can't do the same for XML. For example, i can write it like this

```
    public static bool IsXmlSerializable<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof (T);
        return type.GetInterface("IXmlSerializable") != null;
    }
```

but how can i check that XmlType attribute or something else is used?

Please, advice.

Comment: You can serialize anything, that's why.

Comment: Beware your first version isn't actually correct-- it doesn't check any objects contained or inherited from. It might still fail! Easiest is actually trying to serialize and check for an exception.

Comment: @Sinatr you're right, tnx.

Comment: @Jaapjan lol, I thought type attributes inherits... So strange. But tnx for info anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that shows how to use the isSerializable property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isserializable(v=vs.110).aspx